# Why does my Python script not prompt for user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a complete noob, but why is my python code not prompting for user input within Python 3.7.3 windows command line?

```
user_wants_number = True
while user_wants_number == True:
    print(10)

    user_input = input("Should we print again? (y/n)")
    if user_input == 'n':
        user_wants_number = False

...
user_wants_number = True
while user_wants_number == True:
    print(10)

    user_input = input("Should we print again? (y/n)")
    if user_input == 'n':
        user_wants_number = False
...
```

I expect the output to say "Should we print again?" and for me to say yes or no, and the loop responds accordingly. However, it just keeps printing the number 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem when you type it in the interpreter is the empty line between `print(10)` and `user_input = ...`. The python interpreter considers empty lines to signify the end of a block. In this case, it ends the while block after `print(10)` which means you are effectively executing

```py
while True:
    print(10)
```

Also, there is no need to use the equality operator when checking if something is equal to `True` or `False`, you can simply do `while user_wants_number:`

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly. Doesnt work in the interpreter probably because you have two newlines after `print(10)` and the while loops runs without the input. Put that in a `file.py` and run `python file.py`

Comment: Thanks, when I try to run python file.py it says the specified pathway can't be found. How do you change the directory to the right path in Python terminal/command line?

Comment: You can do `python full/path/to/your/file.py` or you can change directory to the folder with `file.py` with `cd full/path/to/your/` and then `python file.py`.